# Slider jquery and "data-" attributes in HTML5

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I've tried to implement the jquery UI "slider" for the weekdays :

```
<!-- Sliders -->
<span id="sliderList">
    <div id="slider-range-sunday" data-start="14" data-end="18"></div></br/>
    <div id="slider-range-monday" data-start="1" data-end="1"></div></br/>
    <div id="slider-range-tuesday" data-start="1" data-end="1"></div></br/>
    <div id="slider-range-wednesday" data-start="1" data-end="1"></div></br/>
    <div id="slider-range-thursday" data-start="1" data-end="1"></div></br/>
    <div id="slider-range-friday" data-start="1" data-end="1"></div></br/>
    <div id="slider-range-saturday" data-start="1" data-end="1"></div>
</span>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#sliderList > div ").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 24,
        values: [ parseInt($(this).attr("data-start")) , parseInt($(this).attr("data-end"))]
    });
</script>
```

Default values are contained in the "data-start" and "data-end" of the div, but I cannot acces them with :

```
$(this).attr("data-start")
```

I got the below error (debug with chrome)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined 
jquery.ui.slider.js?body=1:204
```

does everyone know why ? 
Thank you

---- EDIT

Now it works thanks to the help of Itay with the below code :

```
$("#sliderList > div ").each(function(index){
    $(this).slider({
         range: true,
         min: 0,
         max: 24,
         values: [ parseInt($(this).attr("data-start")) , parseInt($(this).attr("data-end"))],
         slide: slideTime
     });
});
```

Comment: My real code call the "attr" method (sorry). I also tried with data("start") (it was my first choice) but the same error occured.

Comment: You didn't say what error

Comment: Sorry, I have added error log in my message.

Comment: You have a problem calling the `addClass` method, but the code you posted doesn't show such calls.

Comment: "addClass" is called by Jquery method "slider". I think that values attributes doesn't work.

Comment: if I replace parseInt($(this).attr("data-start") (and "end") by static value ([1,2]), it works...

Comment: Did you try printing `parseInt($(this).attr("data-start")` with `console.log` to see what happens?

Comment: I have tried with :$("#sliderList > div ").click(function(){console.log( $(this).attr("data-start") );});   and "14" was displayed. It sounds like I cannot use "this" as a parameter when calling the slider method.

Comment: Try using each and calculate these values inside it and then call the slider function

Comment: Perfect, it works ~ Can you save your comment as a new message ? (for validate it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the discussion we had on the comments, use the following code (the idea was mine but the writing was all yours, which is great!):

```
$("#sliderList > div ").each(function(){
    $(this).slider({
         range: true,
         min: 0,
         max: 24,
         values: [ parseInt($(this).attr("data-start")),
                   parseInt($(this).attr("data-end"))],
         slide: slideTime
     });
});
```